# SPEDIS (SAS) equivalent in Python

Tags: python, sas

Would appreciate help in finding a Python equivalent of SAS's SPEDIS function, which compares the spelling distance between two strings. e.g. spedis('abc', 'abc')=0.

Thank you!

Comment: Python has packages like difflib and levenshtein for fuzzy string comparison.

Comment: The above comment should really be an answer so that @ShenglinChen can get the appropriate credit.